# Trigger combining in Quartz .NET with C#

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I tried to create a jobtrigger for the following task:

From Monday till Friday
do every 15 minutes {something to do}
between 10:00pm and 11:45pm

I already tried a cron scheduling, but the start and end
have not identical minute values.
I also tried something like 0-30/15 in cron, but then
I do not get 10:45pm f.e.

Is it possible to combine it with .StartAt and EndAt?
This is a possibility I tried, too, but then I get the
error that the trigger will never fire.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `0 0/15 22-23 ? * MON-FRI *` as your schedule.

Explanation:

`0` At 0 seconds

`0/15` At 0 minutes (Repeat every 15)

`22-23` At hour 22 or 23 (10 or 11 pm)

`?` Any day of the month

`*` Every month of the year

`MON-FRI` On a week day

`*` Every year

Because you're specifying 22-23, it won't fire at midnight (since that's hour 0)

You can try cron schedules out for yourself at [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: Since the Quartz.Net implementation doesn't exactly match the one on Cronmaker, you can also check Quartz.Net specific schedules here: http://jayvilalta.com/quartznet/cronexpression

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know there was a Quartz.net implementation of an online checker!

Comment: Okay, that example maybe was a little bit too easy in comparison to the tasks I get. There are also some tasks like 10:00pm-11:59pm repeat 15 minutes or 06:30am-08:00am repeat 30 minutes. Maybe it is too easy but right now at the moment I do not get the clue

Comment: That first task is basically what I gave you. That second task you'd probably want to set it to start at 6:30am and refire every 30 minutes 4 times.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe I was not precise enough:
The task shall fire on every Saturday and Sunday, starting at 06:30am 
and ending at 08:00am and repeat every 30 minutes.
The 30/30 minutes option at cron scheduling just gives me 06:30am and 07:30am but not the 07:00am for example

Comment: Well the thing is there isn't really a way with a single Cron statement to say 6:30 7:00 and 7:30. You could wire up two Cron triggers for the same job- one for 6:30 and 7:30 and a second for 7:00, or not use a Cron trigger at all and say start at 6:30 and repeat every 30 minutes 3 times.